# Trying to get my app to run on armv6 devices, having no luck

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, armv6

I am trying to build a version of my app that runs on older, armv6 iOS devices like it used to. For this,I am using my old Mac Mini running Snow Leopard and Xcode 4.2, rather than my normal dev machine, my MacBook running Lion and Xcode 4.6.3. I set my deployment target to 4.2 for both the project and the target. The app builds fine, but it won't run on an old iPod Touch 2G running 4.2.1 that I am using as a test device. It crashes almost instantly on start up. I made sure it had the proper permissions, but it still doesn't run. I'm not using any 3rd party libraries, only the Apple reachability library. There is no "Required device capabilities" in the info.plist.

Here is the architectures for the project:
[image: Project architectures]

And the target architectures:
[image: Target architectures]

Comment: what does the crash backtrace look like?

Comment: Most likely you are using an API added after 4.2.1 or you have a newer framework linked in (instead of being flagged as weak). When you run the app via Xcode, Xcode should show you the cause of the crash in the console.